# How to merge on project / multiple files in VSS?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, merge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SourceSafe Merge at the project level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031329/sourcesafe-merge-at-the-project-level)

I have VSS 6.0. I have branched my project so that I can do parallel development. I have 100s of files in folder/subfolders. I have changed some 10-20 files in multiple folders in ver 2 branch.

Now I want to merge changes done in ver 2 to ver 1 branch. When I select the project merge branches option is not enabled. neither is it enabled when I select multiple files inside a folder. It's only enabled when one file is selected.

Can I not merge on folder / multiple files in VSS 6.0. My thinking was when I do merge on project, VSS would pop up file names whenever there's a conflict (i.e files that are changed)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031329/sourcesafe-merge-at-the-project-level