# SourceSafe Merge at the project level

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, branch, merge

I'm running SourceSafe and I have two branches of my code. I'm currently using the manual approach of running a report to show differences and then manually merging each file one by one. However I'm trying to find a streamlined way to do this on the project level. It's ok if the process shows me each file one at a time, I'm just worried if I go manually one by one to each file and merge each file separately that I'll accidentally skip a file. Whereas a "wizard" I could trust to hit every file even if it shows me each and every file before merging them.

I'm new to merging but not sourcesafe so I guess you could say I'm a half newbie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there isn't a built-in way to do this through the UI. But they do provide a command line tool which I ended up writing a batch file for to streamline option specification:

```
ECHO OFF
SET SSDIR=K:\Archive

SET /P MainProject=Please enter the project to merge into (e.g. "$/Trunk"):
SET /P BranchedProject=Please enter the branched project (e.g. "$/Active Branches/Branch1"):
SET /P Comment=Comment:

SS CP %MainProject%
IF NOT EXIST C:/BranchCheckouts MKDIR "C:/BranchCheckouts"
IF EXIST "C:/BranchCheckouts/mergelog.txt" DEL "C:/BranchCheckouts/mergelog.txt"
SS MERGE %BranchedProject% -GL"C:/BranchCheckouts" -O@"C:/BranchCheckouts/mergelog.txt" -C%Comment% -R
PAUSE
```